# Java: What does (List<Object>)getCurrentSession() do? (Strange syntax)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is a line I've encountered inside a DAO class:

```
pages.addAll((List<Page>)getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Page.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("path", pagePath))
        .setMaxResults(1).list());
```

I've never seen a method call right after a set of brackets, with no dot in between. Is it just an optional different syntax, or does it do something beyond getting the `session` associated with the `List`?

(Note: Using Java / Spring, and Hibernate `@Transactional` business here)

EDIT: updated to the complete line of code, didn't realise it was significant. Mostly I was thrown by the method-like syntax without the dot.

Comment: Is this the **complete** statement ?

Comment: Paste the full line of code.

Comment: It's probably `(List<Object>)getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT *****").list()` which just casts the `List` returned.

Comment: It's casting the return value of `getCurrentSession()` to a List of Objects...

Comment: @RayStojonic, what a complete nonsense! Check out the API docs, first.

Comment: @kocko Uh, wut? Cast is a cast is a cast. As posted, that's is exactly what the code does.

Comment: edited to update the complete line, but it's mostly the syntax that I'm curious about

Comment: Well, now it casts the result of list() to a List of Objects

Comment: So essentially it was a cast, which I would have recognised, but the lack of space between the bracket and the next statement confused me. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the JLS section on casting: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, the statement

```
getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Page.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("path", pagePath))
    .setMaxResults(1).list()
```

returns a `List` which is then casted to

```
List<Page>
```

Then, the casted object is passed to the `page.addAll()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you missed the complete line

```
(List<Object>) getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Page.class).list();
```

Returns a list of `Page`  objects (pojo's) from database.

Your line

```
pages.addAll((List<Page>)getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Page.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("path", pagePath))
        .setMaxResults(1).list());
```

1)`pages` is a list

2)

```
 (List<Page>)getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Page.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("path", pagePath))
                .setMaxResults(1).list()
```

Here the `list()` method on criteria Object return a list of Objects and here you are casting back them to Page objects,Since you know that they are Page objects

is a criteria to fetch

3) `addAll`  method  adding all results to `pages`